# Allow user to see only their uploaded data (Asp.NET MVC5)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

**I can upload and download the uploaded files, but I want that users to be able to see only their files. (user1 to see only his data, not also user2's data) How could I do it? Any idea could help. Thanks!**

This is my controller, I know that between admin, user, editor I can restrict the access with Authorize, but this wouldn't help me restricting the access between user_id's.

(need to mention that privacy is a very important aspect of my project)

```
public class FileUploadController : Controller
{
    // GET: FileUpload
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = GetFiles();
        return View(items);
    }

    // POST: FileUpload
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if(file != null && file.ContentLength > 0 )
            try
            {

                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files"),
                    Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

                file.SaveAs(path);
                ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
        }

        var items = GetFiles();

        return View(items);

    }


    public FileResult Download(string downloadedfile)
    {
        var FileVirtualPath = "~/Files/" + downloadedfile;

        return File(FileVirtualPath, "application/force-download", Path.GetFileName(FileVirtualPath));

    }



    private List <string> GetFiles()
    {

        var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Files"));
        System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles("*.*");

        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        foreach (var file in fileNames)
        {
            items.Add(file.Name);
        }

        return items;

    }



}
```

This is the view:

```
<h2> File Upload </h2>

@model List<string>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "FileUpload", FormMethod.Post,
        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{


    <label for="file"> Upload </label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    <br /><br />

    @ViewBag.Message

    <br/>

    <h2>Documents list</h2>

    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th> File Name </th>
            <th> Link  </th>
        </tr>

        @for (var i = 0; i <= (Model.Count)-1 ; i++)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>@Model[i].ToString() </td>

                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { downloadedfile = Model[i].ToString() }) </td>

            </tr>

        }


    </table>
}


<style>

        table, th, td {
                        border: 1px solid white;
                      }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate to folder, create a folder with the id of the user, and put the data in user folder.

When you gonna list, only show the folder of the user

Comment: I thought about it, but that wouldn't affect my privacy? Someone could just change their id in the link and access another one's files.

Comment: the user doesnt put his id, you pick the id from the system, the asp.net will give you the id of the user, and you filter by then. I allready did this, it work
It's impossible the user change his id